# Why is Lombok generating an extra Getter when overriding a generic getter?

Tags: java, generics, lombok

I have an interface that defines an id field (and other fields, but simplifying), which uses Java's generics.

And I am using Lombok to generate Getters and a Builder for a class which implements this.

With `IdType getId()` in the interface, Lombok is generating both `Object getId()`, and `UUID getId()`. Both the methods work when called through reflection, but it is deeply weird, and messed up some code that was assuming that a class would not have multiple methods with the same name and different return types.

(I <3 Reflection)

Here's a unit test that shows this behavior. Is my lombokking wrong? Is there another annotation I need to apply? Do I just shrug and write my code to get all the getters to check for this and avoid it?

Java 8, Lombok 1.18.16, currently up to date.

```
public class LombokGeneratesDuplicateMethodsTest {
    interface WithId<IdType> {
        IdType getId();
    }

    @Getter
    @Builder
    static class Record implements WithId<UUID> {
        private UUID id;
        private String name;
    }

    @Test
    public void testStuff() throws Exception {
        Collection<Method> getIds = Arrays.stream(Record.class.getDeclaredMethods())
                .filter(m -> Modifier.isPublic(m.getModifiers()))
                .filter(m -> !Modifier.isStatic(m.getModifiers()))
                .filter(m -> !Void.TYPE.equals(m.getReturnType()))
                .filter(m -> m.getParameterTypes().length == 0)
                .filter(m -> m.getName().equals("getId"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        assertThat(getIds.size()).isEqualTo(2);  // This seems wrong...

        UUID someId = UUID.randomUUID();
        Record record = Record.builder().id(someId).name("Gunter").build();
        for (Method getId : getIds) {
            assertThat(getId.invoke(record)).isEqualTo(someId);
        }

        WithId<UUID> withId = record;
        assertThat(withId.getId()).isEqualTo(someId);
        assertThat(record.getId()).isEqualTo(someId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204339/java-class-getmethods-behavior-on-overridden-methods/6204573 , seems you need to filter on isBridge(), too

Answer (score 6):

Has nothing to do with Lombok.

Try it. Write this code:

```
interface Example<T> {
    T get();
}

class Foo implements Example<String> {
    public String get() {return null;}
}
```

then:

```
>javac Foo.java
>javap Foo
Compiled from "Foo.java"
class Foo implements Example<java.lang.String> {
  Foo();
  public java.lang.String get();
  public java.lang.Object get();
}
```

This is in the JLS. The Object-returning method is called a synthetic bridger. It's there, but not particularly visible to `javac` (javac knows about it, but acts as if it does not exist). At the class file level (so, JVMs, and to some extent, reflection), it does exist.

So, how to fix?

Check for the synthetic flag. It'll be set for the Object-returning one:

```
class Foo implements Example<String> {
        public String get() {return null;}

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                for (Method m : Foo.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                        System.out.println(m.getReturnType() + " " + m.getName() + ": " + m.isSynthetic());
                }
        }
}
```

then:

```
> javac Foo.java; java Foo
void main: false
class java.lang.String get: false
class java.lang.Object get: true
```

> (I <3 Reflection)

At risk of raining on your parade, this is... not a good mindset for a good java programmer in my opinion. Java doesn't make reflection easy, and the tooling mostly assume you don't aggressively use it either. For example, refactor scripts don't do well when you call a bunch of methods using reflection instead of actually calling them.